# Why does this loop only work on the homepage?

Tags: theme-development, loop

I've been trying to figure this out all day now.

Consider the following code below:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides"><?php
       wp_reset_query();
         if(have_posts()) : 
           while (have_posts()) : 
             the_post();
             if(is_sticky()) : ?>
               <div class="slide"><a rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></div>
             <?php endif;
           endwhile; 
         else: ?>
           <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
         <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="left-arrow"></div>
      <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The loop above doesn't work on the site's pages (e.g: page 2/3/4) or 404.php, but works perfectly fine on page 1 (the index.php).

Why is that and how do I fix this?

Comment: Why the `wp_reset_query()`?

Comment: Nothing really. I thought that WordPress wasn't querying the right stuff, so I added it to double check. It functions the same without the `wp_reset_query`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at that code carefully, the only thing it ever prints are sticky posts:

```
if(is_sticky()) : ?>
   <div class="slide"><a rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></div>
<?php endif;
```

You stand a better chance of having sticky posts on page 1 of the index than on any page thereafter. 404 pages don't have posts at all, sticky or not. That is why they are 404 pages.

I think that is why the code ***appears*** not to work on some pages, but it isn't that the code is broken, just that the conditions for printing post data and not met.

Comment: Are you saying that the sticky posts are pulled from the current page? I specifically use a different loop than the one for pagination.

Comment: Sticky posts are pushed (copied, I believe) to the beginning of the query results. I suppose you could have multiple pages of sticky posts but that seems unlikely. But also seems somewhat besides the point. Your Loop ___will only display sticky posts___, and that means it won't print anything, chances are, for many of the pages on the site.

Comment: Ah, but the point of sticky posts was intentional. The algorithm was planned to get all the sticky posts on the blog and display them in the slider. If I am understanding you correctly, my loop is actually incorrect in terms of its purpose, because you reference multiple pages of sticky posts, which is not what I was aiming for.

Comment: You said that the Loop "doesn't work on the site's pages (e.g: page 2/3/4) or 404.php" and asked why. That is what I attempted to answer. You did not mention that this was a secondary loop, and really, it sounds like it isn't. You are trying to use the exiting query, which won't work. You should be using `WP_Query` to get your posts for this "sticky only" Loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your recommendation works perfectly. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if(is_sticky())` and the `endif` code from the below snippet:

```
if(is_sticky()) : ?>
                <div class="slide"><a rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></div>
  <?php endif;
```

This conditional statement tells WordPress only to run if the post is sticky. Typically sticky posts appear on page 1 only.